# Ionic/Angular ng-repeat keeps requesting the data after I left the view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In an Ionic app, I have a (hidden) tab with a list populated with ng-repeat:

```
<!-- ng-repeat that gets its items through a function -->
<ion-item ng-repeat="product in getProducts()">

//The function that provides the list back (+filter in my real code)
$scope.getProducts = function () {
  console.log('In getProducts');
  return $scope.list;
};
```

All works fine, except that I notice that this getProducts function is called much too often, even when I left the view already. I have no clue what is causing this, but I was able to reproduce this easily in Plnkr: https://embed.plnkr.co/BspdtQ/

To see the issue: in the home tab, click the 'add item' button which will navigate to the other tab. In the console you will see it is firing the function as expected.
Now click on some of the other tabs, and you'll see it keeps processing that same code while not in the view anymore.

What is causing the ng-repeat to refresh? What am I missing here?

---

**Update**

As a workaround, I disabled caching of the specific view so all items in scope get destroyed and are thus not processed anymore.

Comment: interesting....why dont you just do `product in list`  ?

Comment: @EkanshRastogi Hi, I made a very simplified version for the plnkr. In my real code, the getProducts() performs a filter `return $scope.list.filter(...)` that only displays items that match a search criterium.

Comment: well... you can watch the conditions to change your list, and then, filter and store on a direct variable... The extra calls occur because the hidden div continues active, and the watches of ng-repeat continue active.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `ng-repeat` tries to evaluate the products at each digest to see if there are changes. So in your case, `getProduct()` is called multiple times.

If you want to filter your products, you can create a custom angular filter and use the `filter` built-in instruction in `ng-repeat`.

**HTML**

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="product in products | filterProducts">
    <h2>{{product.name}}</h2>
</ion-item>
```

**JS**

```
app.filter('filterProducts', function () {
  return function (product) {
    // your filter function
    return product;
  };
});
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, but after trying this it does not seem to solve the issue

Comment: As I said, it's a normal behaviour. Angular tries to evaluate your products at each digest cycle. So a filter won't change this.

Comment: Actually, why is it bothering you?

Comment: It gets triggered on any kind of action in any tab. Eg in another tab I have a chain of 5 promises for a certain action. At that point it will go through my list of hundreds of items to filter them, and this 5 times. This means a*lot* of wasted processing power during any action taking place on completely unrelated tabs. I doubt this is normal behavior, or at least that should than be considered a bug?
Is there any way I can isolate the scope of the tabs more?